# How to open a directory with spaces in its name from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change directory to a folder with special characters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101587/how-do-i-change-directory-to-a-folder-with-special-characters)

I am trying to open dir in Terminator, but when I want to open dir that consists of two or more words I get error message like this:

```
bash: cd: /home/kudic/Radna: There is no directory Radna
```

The error message is on croatian language so I have translated it.

The name of dir I want to open is:

```
Radna površina
```