# keeping a string (specially ! sign) in a variable and displaying it

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to put a string (comprising of specially `!` sign) in a variable, say,

```
var="!f then"
```

Then I want to display the string or use it elsewhere:

```
echo $var
```

But when I enter with `var="!f then"` it gives the following:

```
var="for f in Tor*; do mv "$f" "$f-Win"; done then"
```

If I use escape like `var="\!f then"`, then the escape character also comes in the string.

```
$ echo $var  
\\!f then
```

How can I use `!` as an element in a string?

Comment: If you aren't actively using history expansion, your life will be much easier if you turn it off.  At the command line, run `set +H`.  To keep it off, put `set +H` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [`bash` History Expansion](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc29) you're experiencing:

```
!string
  Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position
  in the history list starting with string.
```

As I explain [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051), history expansion is performed inside double quotes, so two ways to quote remain for `!`:

```bsh
var=\!f\ then # either use <b>only</b> backslash
var='!f then' # or just single quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

The `!` character is a special character that `bash` uses to introduce a history command (see `man bash`), and is used like `!!` to re-execute the next command. Use `\!` instead.

Comment: then the escape character "\" is also displayed (printed) in echo