# Copy images in bash without changing subfolders

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, copy

Can I copy `*.png` files without change subfolders address and name?

Example:
Copy `/photo` to `/pic` converting `/photo/2017/hello.png` to `/pic/2017/hello.png`.

Comment: You can use `rsync`.

Comment: Do you want to keep both `/photo` and `/pic` folders?

Comment: It should be something like this: `mkdir -p pic/2017/ && cp photo/2017/*.png pic/2017/`.

Comment: Yes i want to keep both

Comment: @velix is that not an answer?

Comment: No. The number of files and directorys is too much

Comment: What files and directories are you referring to? Please edit your question to better explain  the main folder hierarchy.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I’m curius: How can `rsync` make the task easier as compared to `cp`? Please add an answer!

Comment: @dessert I'd prefer rsync over cp for copying large amounts of data even
locally because if it stopped it will only copy files that have not
been copied yet the next time it's started.  Also, I have bad
experience with other tools, for example a few years ago I tried to
use scp to copy a few gigabytes of data over ssh and it crashed but
rsync did the job.

Answer (score 1):

First create the directory you want to copy to:

```
mkdir -p pic/2017
```

Then copy over the files. Normally one would just need `cp`:

```
cp photo/2017/*.png pic/2017/
```

As you mentioned there are too many files and you probably receive an “Argument list too long” error, we’ll use `printf` and `xargs` to run `cp` as often as necessary:

```
printf "%s\0" photo/2017/*.png | xargs -0 cp -t pic/2017/
```

You can also use `mcp` from the [`mmv` package[image: Install mmv]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/mmv) in the following way:

```
mcp -n "photo/2017/*.png" pic/2017/
```

`-n` let’s `mcp` only list the changes, remove it to actually perform the copying. Note the [quoted](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051) asterisk: It’s not evaluated by the shell, but rather by `mcp`.

Comment: But in 2017, there are not all of the files. Some:
/photo/2017/11
  I do not know about these

Comment: @AmirhosseinWP Seems like your question is unclear then – please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1046350/edit) and add the actual file structure, as it is and as you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to copy the directory recursively, so, you should do:

```
cp -a /photo /pic
```

This will copy all files and directories recursively and preserves file metadata.

If `/photo` has files that are not `png` files that you do not want to copy, you can do this after doing the above command:

```
find /pic -not -iname '*.png' -type f -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 rm
```