# Is there a way to create a script and make it executable in less code than this?

Tags: command-line, scripts

My code to create an executable script

```
touch script.sh && echo "echo 'Hello World'" > script.sh && sudo chmod +x script.sh
```

Comment: @ShamFiorin I wanted to emphasize the first part of desserts answer. You should try to use `sudo` very sparingly. Getting into the habit of throwing it around can be dangerous. In this case you own the script you created so you can do what ever you please with the permissions, no sudo needed.

Comment: Related in a general way: [Tips for golfing in Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can leave out the whole `touch` command and there’s no need to use `sudo`. To shorten the command line further you can use [`bash` History Expansion](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#history%20expansion) to save the filename the second time, and omit unnecessary spaces:

```bsh
echo "echo 'Hello World'" >script.sh&&chmod +x !#:3
```

History Expansion replaces `!#:3` with the fourth word from the current command line, which in your case is the filename `script.sh`. Of course this needs to be adapted in case you modify the first command, e.g.:

```bsh
>script.sh echo "echo 'Hello World'"&&chmod +x !#:1
```

Note that a valid script needs a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```bsh
>script.sh echo -e "#!/bin/bash\necho 'Hello World'"&&chmod +x !#:1
```

If you need this chain of commands more often I recommend [defining a function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html), this way you’d just need to type the function name. A similarly adaptable – though longer – way is the use of a variable holding the filename:

```bsh
f=script.sh;>$f echo "echo 'Hello World'"&&chmod +x $f
```

If your filename contains special characters don’t forget to [quote them properly](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051).

Answer (score 20):

The [`install`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/install-invocation.html) command (part of GNU coreutils along with `cp`, `mv`, `rm`, etc.) can copy a file while also setting its ownership and permissions and creating parent directories as necessary. By default it will make the new file executable. It doesn’t understand ‘`-`’ but `/dev/stdin` can be used instead:

```
install /dev/stdin script.sh <<< "echo Hello World"
```

The above uses a ‘[here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings)’ to provide the text on stdin, which is slightly shorter than piping it in. The arguments to `echo` don’t need quoting unless they contain characters with special meaning.

Comment: note that herestring is a Bashism - a heredoc would be portable

Comment: Nice idea.  You could also use a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html): `install <(echo echo Hello World) script.sh`

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to use `cat` for tasks like this:

```
cat > script.sh && chmod +x script.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Hello World'Enter
Ctrl+D
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also leave out the whole chmod and use umask instead before the echo. Should save you a few bytes. Shebang is optional as long as you use commands that are understood by every shell (bourne and C mainly).

Comment: How would you do that exactly?

Comment: It's not possible to use `umask` for setting executable bit by default...