# In a bash script how do I pass a variable integer to a 'sed -e' command (18.04)

Tags: bash, scripts, sed

I'm trying to create a bash script that trashes the oldest files in a directory with a variable setting the amount of files to retain.

My first step was to count the number of files older than a set number of 10 newest files to be retained:

```
#!/bin/bash
# How many files in the current directory are older than the retained files
olderThanRetain=$(find -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -r | sed -e '1,10d' | wc -l)
echo $olderThanRetain
```

Works fine.

But when I try and set a variable for the number of files to be retained:

```
#!/bin/bash
retain=10
# How many files in the current directory are older than the retained files
olderThanRetain=$(find -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -r | sed -e "1,(( $retain ))d" | wc -l)
echo $olderThanRetain
```

But this gives me the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comma is not a special character in `bash` there’s not need to quote this expression at all, you can simply use:

```
sed 1,${retain}d
```

To avoid problems with strange filenames (imagine a filename with a newline), use `0` as the line delimiter. Also I‘m not quite sure what you’re sorting there, to reversely sort by last access time I‘d do:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%A@ %p\0" | sort -zr | sed -z 's/[^ ]* //;'1,${retain}d
```

You can change `0` to newline with `tr \\0 \\n`. To count zero-delimited lines you can use `tr -cd '\0' | wc -c`, see [Count nul delimited items in file · U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164988/246819).

#### Explanations

- `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%A@ %p\0"` – find every file (`-type f`) in the current directory without searching subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`) and print `"%A@ %p\0"` (without a newline!) for it.
  `%A@` is replaced by the file’s access time in [seconds since epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), `%p` by the file name and `\0` by [the null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), see [`man find`/EXPRESSION/ACTIONS/-printf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html#expression) for the full list of escapes and directives.
- `sort -zr` – sort `z`ero-delimited data in `r`everse order
- `sed -z 'a;b` – run the `sed` expressions a and b on every entry with `z`ero as the entry delimiter
  You only need to quote characters special to the shell, see [my post on quoting here](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051). In fact in this case the only thing you need to quote is `;` (by escaping or with single or double quotes), so `sed -z s/[^ ]* //\;1,${retain}d` is fine as well.

  - `s/[^ ]* //` – `s`ubstitute the first string not containing the space character (= everything until the first space character) and the space character that follows it with nothing (= delete it)
  - `1,${retain}d` – delete the first `$retain` entries