# Escape $ in password

Tags: bash

How should I escape special characters in bash

```
flyway info -url="jdbc:redshift://server_name/db_name?ssl=true&sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory" -password='$PROD_PASSWORD'

PROD_PASSWORD=sf45$h)jY*@hj
```

I want to escape the dollar sign 
I tried escape `\` and putting `password='$PROD_PASSWORD'` and also `password="$PROD_PASSWORD"` also `%40`.

Comment: I tried to answer this thoroughly [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051). You’re quoting the wrong thing, try `PROD_PASSWORD='sf45$h)jY*@hj'` and `password="$PROD_PASSWORD"`.

Comment: Also, you should first fill the variable and then use it, not the other way around. :)

Comment: it did not work, PROD_PASSWORD='sf45$h)jY*@hj' and password="$PROD_PASSWORD" , my build failed

Comment: @user_01_02 just for the record, I suppose this is a dummy password, right?

Answer (score 1):

Bash uses single quotes (`'`) to avoid any special characters or the backslash (`\`) to escape a single character:

```
MY_VARIABLE='$foo'
echo "$MY_VARIABLE"
```

This will output `$foo` as will:

```
echo '\$foo'
```

Comment: Try to be more specific in answering the question, if possible. That means in this case: use variable names and assignments given in the question to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: I really don't want to condone such usage of variables or repeat his "production password" anymore to be honest!