# How to move files from subdirectories that have the same directory name to its relative upper/parent directory?

Tags: command-line, directory, batch-rename

So, I have a directory structure like this:

```
parent/
├── sub1
│   └── source
│       └── file1
│       └── file2
├── sub2
│   └── sub2.1
│       └── source
│           └── something1
│           └── something2
└── sub3
    └── sub3.1
        └── sub3.1.1
            └── source
                └── other.zip
```

I want to move **all files** (with different filename) from **all directories named `source`** to its relative upper/parent directory. So, the result should be something like this:

```
parent/
├── sub1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── source
├── sub2
│   └── sub2.1
│       ├── something1
│       ├── something2
│       └── source
└── sub3
    └── sub3.1
        └── sub3.1.1
            ├── other.zip
            └── source
```

Is there an easy way (*one liner*) to accomplish this, maybe using the `find` command?
Preferably one that's not too complex for me to understand. :D I'm quite new to Linux.

**EDIT:** I'm also going to make a bash script (so I can use it easily) out of the solution. For example: `./movefiles.sh myfolder`
So, preferably, the solution can easily accommodate, umm variables?, especially ones that have symbols like `.` (if it's a hidden directory), `#`, `@`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a `find` solution, you could use this:

```
find parent -name "source" -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$1"; mv * ..' bash {} \;
```

Explanation:

- `find parent -name "source" -type d` - For each directory named `source` in `parent`...
- `-exec bash -c '...' bash {} \;` - Call Bash with `bash` as `$0` and the directory path as `$1`
- `cd "$1"; mv * ..` - cd into the directory; move all its contents up one level.

  - Alternative: `mv "$1"/* "$1/.."`

This is more or less based on [dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089228/301745).

#### Including hidden files

```
find parent -name "source" -type d -exec bash -c 'shopt -s dotglob; cd "$1"; mv * ..' bash {} \;
```

- `shopt -s dotglob` - Make globs include hidden files

Answer (score 8):

A simple `for` loop with the `globstar` option enabled (run `shopt -s globstar` to do that) will do the job:

```
dirname="source"
for i in ./**/"$dirname"/; do
  mv "$i"* "${i%$dirname/}"
done
```

The [GNU `parallel` [image: Install parallel]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parallel) equivalent for this loop is:

```
parallel mv {}* {//}/ ::: ./**/"$dirname"/
```

A totally different approach is to use `rename` to remove the “$dirname/” part from the string:

```
rename "s/$dirname\///" **/"$dirname"/*
```

[Quoting](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051) with double quotes as I did here preserves the meaning of every special character except `$`, `` ` ``, `\` and `!`. If you want to include “hidden” dot files in any of the above solutions, set the `dotglob` option before running it: `shopt -s dotglob`

#### Explanation

> globstar
>    If set, the pattern `**` used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories
>   and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match.

`./**/source/` matches every directory named `source` in and under the current directory, the `mv` command moves every file from inside the directory to its parent directory – `${i%source/}` is a parameter expansion which removes the string `source/` from the end of the (path) string.

#### Example run

```
$ tree
.
├── sub1
│   └── source
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
├── sub2
│   └── sub2.1
│       └── source
│           ├── something1
│           └── something2
└── sub3
    └── sub3.1
        └── sub3.1.1
            └── source
                └── other.zip

$ dirname="source"
$ for i in ./**/"$dirname"/; do mv "$i"* "${i%$dirname/}"; done
$ tree
.
├── sub1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── source
├── sub2
│   └── sub2.1
│       ├── something1
│       ├── something2
│       └── source
└── sub3
    └── sub3.1
        └── sub3.1.1
            ├── other.zip
            └── source
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to get what you want:

```
dir=$(find . -name 'source' | sed s:source::)
for path in $dir; do
    mv "$path"source/* "$path"
done
```

The `find` command returns the directory path from parent to source directory. In this `find . -name 'source'` '.' represents the parent directory and 'source' represents the subdirectory you want to find.

The `sed` command removes `source` from the result of `find` command.

And the rest is just iteration (`for`) and move command (`mv`)

Answer (score 2):

For these kinds of tasks where there might be surprises, **one of the best ways is "script-a-script"**.  We run a command which outputs a script, usually very repetitive, to do the task.  Once we're satisfied it's correct, we pipe that through `sh` to run it.  This turns a complex problem into a much simpler edit problem, and it's an **extremely general technique**, applicable to all kinds of problems, not just this fiddly move-some-files-upstairs problem.  It has the advantage of not using any exotic shell constructions, and so will work in every shell (pure Posix `sh`, `bash`, `csh`, and so on).  Because you see all the basic commands before they are executed, it's a good example of **"look-before-you-leap"**.

First find all the directories we're going to modify:

```
$ find . -type d -name source
```

This gives

```
./sub3/sub3.1/sub3.1.1/source
./sub2/sub2.1/source
./sub1/source
```

Then for each of those directories we want to move the contents up one directory, we think of the command we'd run:

```
$ mv $dir/* $dir/..
```

We use `awk` (or `sed` or whatever) to write the commands.  So we pipe the list of directories into awk:

```
$ find . -type d -name source \
  | awk '{printf("mv %s/* %s/..\n", $0, $0);}'
mv ./sub3/sub3.1/sub3.1.1/source/* ./sub3/sub3.1/sub3.1.1/source/..
mv ./sub2/sub2.1/source/* ./sub2/sub2.1/source/..
mv ./sub1/source/* ./sub1/source/..
```

We can do this as many times as necessary, editing carefully, until we see the commands are correct.

Then we pipe all of that through `sh` to actually do it:

```
$ find . -type d -name source \
  | awk '{printf("mv %s/* %s/..\n", $0, $0);}' \
  | sh
```

Often good to have the final output say what it's doing, and exit on first error, so use `sh -e -x`:

```
$ find . -type d -name source  \
  | awk '{printf("mv %s/* %s/..\n", $0, $0);}' \
  | sh -e -x
```

---

If you're not confident with `awk` for this editing, you can do it with `sed` or pure `find`

```
find . -type d -name source | sed 's|\(.*\)|mv \1/* \1/..|'  # sed
find . -type d -name source -exec echo 'mv {}/* {}/..' ';'   # find/echo
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested find command will do the job in a single line, but this may appear a little quirky. ;-)

Specifically:

```
find . -name source -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -type f -execdir mv "{""}"  .. \;' {} \;
```

### Explanation:

- `find . -name source -type d` finds all directories named `source` in the current (`.`) directory.
- `-exec sh -c '...' {} \;` executes a `sh` with command `'...'` for every found directory, plugs the directory name into `{}`, and furthermore defines the executed `sh`'s variable `$0` with the contents of `{}` (see the option `-c` in the `sh` manpage)
- the argument to `sh -c`, `'find "$0" -type f ... '` finds all files within the directory `$0`
- and finally `... -execdir mv "{""}" ..`  moves the found files `{}` (here cloaked as `"{""}"` to prevent replacement due to the upstream `-exec`) to the (directory-local - therefore `-execdir`) parent directory `..`

### Example run:

```
marcus@gargabuntu:~/temp$ tree
.
├── sub1
│   └── source
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
├── sub2
│   └── sub2.1
│       └── source
│           ├── something1
│           └── something2
└── sub3
    └── sub3.1
        └── sub3.1.1
            └── source
                └── other.zip

9 directories, 5 files
marcus@gargabuntu:~/temp$ find . -name source -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -type f -execdir mv "{""}"  .. \;' {} \;
marcus@gargabuntu:~/temp$ tree
.
├── sub1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── source
├── sub2
│   └── sub2.1
│       ├── something1
│       ├── something2
│       └── source
└── sub3
    └── sub3.1
        └── sub3.1.1
            ├── other.zip
            └── source

9 directories, 5 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one

```
dir='source'
for i in `find . -name  "*" | grep $dir/*| grep -v "$dir$"`; do
mv "$i" "${i%$dir/*}"
done
```

Test

```
$ cd Desktop/test/
/Desktop/test$ tree
.
├── sub1
│   └── source
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
├── sub2
│   └── sub2.1
│       └── source
│           ├── something1
│           └── something2
└── sub3
    └── sub3.1
        └── sub3.1.1
            └── source
                └── other.zip

9 directories, 5 files
/Desktop/test$ dir='source'
/Desktop/test$ for i in `find . -name  "*" | grep $dir/*| grep -v "$dir$"`; do
>    mv "$i" "${i%$dir/*}"
> done
/Desktop/test$ tree
.
├── sub1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── source
├── sub2
│   └── sub2.1
│       ├── something1
│       ├── something2
│       └── source
└── sub3
    └── sub3.1
        └── sub3.1.1
            ├── other.zip
            └── source

9 directories, 5 files
/Desktop/test$
```