# How to rename (unhide) all files and subdirectories within a directory?

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I want to make a script to "unhide" all files and directories inside a certain directory **in one go**, e.g. `./unhide test`.

```
test/
├── sub1
│   └── .hiddenfile1
└── sub2
    └── .hiddendir
        ├── .hiddendirsub
        ├── .hiddenfile2
        └── not.hidden
```

Desired outcome:

```
test/
├── sub1
│   └── hiddenfile1
└── sub2
    └── hiddendir
        ├── hiddendirsub
        ├── hiddenfile2
        └── not.hidden
```

How can I do that?

I'm still new to this and I've been trying to find a solution using `find`, but stuck at `-exec`, and `rename` (or `mv`) because I'm still struggling to understand how this combination works. :(
So, I'll appreciate if anyone here can give a solution and detailed explanation as well. Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that changing the filename (removing the leading dot) might break functionality that expect the hidden filename?

Comment: @SorenA Yes. Fortunately, I'm not going to change/mess with those kinds of files (files that "need" to be hidden).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with `find` as follows:

```bsh
find /path/to/test -depth -name ".*" -execdir rename -n 's|/\.|/|' {} +
```

This only prints the renaming actions, if it shows what you want remove the `-n` option.

#### Explanations

- `-depth` – lets `find` process from bottom to top, renaming files before their parent directories
- `-name ".*"` – lets `find` search for files ([everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)) beginning with a dot – the dot is literal here, as this is not a regular expression
- `-execdir … +` – execute `…` in the matched file‘s directory
- `rename 's|/\.|/|' {}` – replace the first occurence of “/.” from the matched file’s path (`find`’s placeholder for which is `{}`) with “/”, essentially removing the dot from the beginning of the filename
  This would be e.g. `rename 's|/\.|/|' ./.hiddenfile1` in your case, this would be renamed to `./hiddenfile1`.

#### Example run

```bsh
$ tree -a
.
├── sub1
│   └── .hiddenfile1
└── sub2
    └── .hiddendir
        ├── .hiddendirsub
        ├── .hiddenfile2
        └── not.hidden

$ find ~/test -depth -name ".*" -execdir rename 's|/\.|/|' {} +
$ tree -a
.
├── sub1
│   └── hiddenfile1
└── sub2
    └── hiddendir
        ├── hiddendirsub
        ├── hiddenfile2
        └── not.hidden
```

#### Usage in a script

In a script you can simply use positional parameters instead of the path, it may be relative or absolute – just remember to [quote correctly](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
find "$1" -depth -name ".*" -execdir rename -n 's|/\.|/|' {} +
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ tree -a test
test
├── .alsohidden
├── sub1
│   └── .hiddenfile1
└── sub2
    ├── .hiddendirsub
    ├── .hiddenfile2
    └── not.hidden

3 directories, 4 files
```

---

```
$ find test/ -depth -name ".*" -exec rename -n 's|(.*/)\.(.*)|$1$2|' {} +
rename(test/.alsohidden, test/alsohidden)
rename(test/sub2/.hiddendirsub, test/sub2/hiddendirsub)
rename(test/sub2/.hiddenfile2, test/sub2/hiddenfile2)
rename(test/sub1/.hiddenfile1, test/sub1/hiddenfile1)
```

- `find test/` begin paths with `test/`, search recursively from this path
- `-depth` stolen from [dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089493/527764) - seemed like a good idea
- `-name ".*"` filename starts with `.`
- `-exec command {} +` run *`command`* on the found files, constructing an argument list.
- `rename -n` do not do anything, only show what will be done (remove `-n` after testing to actually rename)
- `s|old|new|` replace `old` with `new`
- `(.*/)\.(.*)` save all the chars up to and including the last directory separator`/`, skip a literal `.`, save all the subsequent characters
- `$1$2` print the saved patterns

Comment: Why does `rename` accept “|” as a delimiter, but not “_”? Should I ask a new question? ;)

Comment: @dessert omg I just assumed it would allow, I always use `|` if I need `/` in the regex (unless I need `|`). That would be a good question. Maybe it has to be a non-word char or there's a set of permitted chars

Comment: @Zanna I think this needs `-depth` like the answer from @dessert. I tried it and it gave errors `Can't rename test/sub2/.hiddendir/.hiddenfile2 test/sub2/.hiddendir/hiddenfile2: No such file or directory
Can't rename test/sub2/.hiddendir/.hiddendirsub test/sub2/.hiddendir/hiddendirsub: No such file or directory`

Comment: @LukmanHakim thanks for your advice - I added it, although I couldn't get those errors I'm probably just lucky :)

Comment: @Zanna try with a path where both a directory and a file inside it are to be renamed, e.g. `test/.dir/.file – without `-depth`, `test/.dir` is renamed first and renaming `test/.dir/.file` then obviously fails.