# auto edit a text file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

first let me say I have been teaching myself Linux, and I am not "techie" knowledgeable yet.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and find myself using the BASH to create files I can run.  One thing I am trying to do is this.  I love ASCII art.  I want to create a script that will take the file I tell it (ex: `./convert moon`) `moon` being a text file containing the ASCII art.  I want to get the script to edit the file I tell it to edit each line with `echo "` at the beginning, and `"` at the end of the line, for each line in the file.  Lastly put the `#!/bin/bash` statement as the first line.  I have been experimenting with different methods, but can't seem to get it right.  If this was a Windows BAT file I would have no problems doing this.  So any help anyone can give will be greatly welcomed...thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want this? What would be the use for that script? I mean, what is the benefit of creating a script to output what you already have in the file? Why not just `cat moon`?

Comment: files that contain ANSI pictures have command variables like / \  in them to makeup the picture.  Back in the day, ANSI.SYS would handle this quite nicely when you ran it, and if color if any.  That is the problem I was running into when ran, the system would think certain characters was variables and return errors.  To avoid this I needed to put the  echo " at the start and the closing  " ending of each line doing it manually takes alot of time if you have a large picture.  Yes I know it might seem stupid to some, but I happen to like ASCII and ANSI artwork

Comment: Nothing stupid about that, I just don't understand why you are saying the `echo` will make a difference. Adding `echo` to each line will result in exactly the same thing as simply running `cat file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Remember to quote special characters, I wrote [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051) covering this topic.</sub>

That can actually be done with a single `sed` call:

```
<moon sed -e 's/.*/echo "&"/' -e '1s_^_#!/bin/bash\n_' >moon.bash
```

This takes `moon` as the input file, the first expression substitutes every line with “echo "*original line content*"”, the second one substitutes the first line‘s beginning with the shebang followed by a newline character, and the output is stored as `moon.bash`.

If you use it regularly, I recommend adding it as a function to your `~/.bashrc` file, e.g.:

```
ascii_convert(){ <$1 sed -e 's/.*/echo "&"/' -e '1s_^_#!/bin/bash\n_' >$1.bash ;}
```

(Don’t forget to save the file and source it with `. ~/.bashrc` ) This way you can convert any file with a simple:

```
ascii_convert moon
```

#### Example run

```
$ cat moon
1
2
3
$ ascii_convert moon
$ cat moon.bash 
#!/bin/bash
echo "1"
echo "2"
echo "3"
```

Comment: Use this script very careful! You will get errors if you have " symbol in any line of source script\file. @dessert if you can, add alternative script which escape **"** symbols in lines.