# How to send output of convert to a writable directory in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to convert `.tbl` files to `.csv` in `/data/` directory which I've got read-only access.
I'm using this command:

```
for i in `ls *.tbl`; do
    sed 's/|$//' $i > ${i/tbl/csv}
    echo $i
done
```

But I'm getting:

```
-bash: supplier.csv: Permission denied
```

And I don't know how to change the script such that it could save the output in a writable directory.
Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify a different path:

```
for tbl in *.tbl ; do
    sed 's/|$//' "$tbl" > /another/path/"${tbl%.tbl}".csv
    echo "$tbl"
done
```

Few minor fixes:

1. Don't parse the output of `ls`, just iterate over an expanded wildcard pattern.
2. Double quote variables (filenames can contain whitespace).
3. I used Remove Matching Suffix instead of Substitution.

Answer (score 4):

Just specify the path (here `/path/to/writable/dir/`) before the filename:

```bsh
for i in *.tbl; do
  sed 's/|$//' "$i" >"/path/to/writable/dir/${i/%tbl/csv}"
  echo "$i"
done
```

You should never parse the output of `ls` ([Why?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)) and always [quote](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051) variables like `$i` here. Adding `%` at the pattern’s beginning makes it match against the end of the string so that a filename like `tbl.tbl` becomes `tbl.csv` rather than `csv.tbl`. Read more about Parameter expansion [here on bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace).