# Replace String "Development" with "Staging" or "Production" using SED

Tags: command-line, sed

I am trying to replace the string

```
: 'development'
```

with

```
: 'production'
```

using `sed`.

I tried a few options including:

```
sed -i "s|: \'development\'|: \'staging\'|g" index.php
```

but without any luck. Output:

```
sed: 1: "index.php": command i expects \ followed by text
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need to escape single quotes inside double quotes, see [this answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`.

Thus, these work:

```bsh
sed -i "s/: 'development'/: 'staging'/g" index.php
sed -i "s|: 'development'|: 'staging'|g" index.php
sed -i 's|: '\''development'\''|: '\''staging'\''|g' index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
sed "s/: 'development'/: 'production'/" index.php`
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it out.
Turned out in mac machine I have to postfix .bak with -i. But in Linux it worked without it. I was first trying it in my local machine to see the output and it was failing.

Thank you all for your help.