# File's order got destroyed while grepping and echoing into for loop

Tags: command-line, grep, echo

I want to write the result of grep inside for loop into a file, keeping original file structure.
Original file:

```
$cat newtest1
some_text
/homes/myself/joz
ivan petrov - 20/10/19
new customer:
/homes/myself/silvia
john smith - 30/11/19
old customer:
some_text
```

I am using grep in for loop and getting the following:

```
$for i in `cat newtest1 | grep customer -B2`; do echo $i; done
/homes/myself/joz
ivan
petrov
-
```

etc.
File's structure got changed. 
I tried printf - the same result.
Question: how to keep file's structure using grep in for loop?

Comment: What's your intent with the `for` loop? Why not just the `grep`?

Comment: For I want to use some ifs inside for loop.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) - for example how to process 3-line records that are delimited by the string "customer:"

Comment: The question was asked exactly about what I needed and the answer helped. It was meaningless for me to include if  statements, since I had no question about if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [quote](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051) variables and the result of command substitution to prevent word splitting:

```bsh
for i in "$(<newtest1 grep customer -B2)"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Of course to just output the matching lines you don’t need the `for` loop, but I suppose you want to do other things with the lines. In any case you don’t need the `cat`, you can let `grep` open the file with `grep … newtest1` or let the shell open it and assign its content to `grep`’s stdin as I did above. The latter has a number of advantages explained in this great answer: [When should I use input redirection?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759/246819)