# single quote and double quotes in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I tested the single quote and double quotes in sed

```
me@host:~:
$ echo "front" | sed "s/front/back/"
back
me@host:~:
$ echo "front" | sed 's/front/back/'
back
```

They performed identically,  but I remembered to read there exist differences between them months ago.

Google search not helpful with keywords "single quotes and double quotes in sed".

They are not identically, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enter a file or directory with special characters in its name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101587/how-do-i-enter-a-file-or-directory-with-special-characters-in-its-name) – I explain the specifics in [my answer there](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051).

Comment: You should stick to single quotes, unless you want to interpolate variables. If that is the case, you should pay attention because the `$` sigil has a specific meaning in sed.

Comment: ty and upvoted, I heard the decent advice many times, but I wonder if stick to double quotes, one don't have to pay attentions to the `$`, what the proofs for the sticking to single for an convention? @simlev

Comment: @DummyHead Here's another approach: if you use single quotes, the sed command is exactly as you type it. If you use double quotes, you must take into account all shell substitutions and elaborations to "visualize" what command is eventually passed on to sed.

Comment: could you please transmit the comment into answer. @simlev

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm expanding my earlier comments into an answer.

My advice would be sticking to single quotes, unless you know what you're doing and need to take advantage of some command-line functionality. The most common cases that come to mind are single quotes inside text strings and shell variable interpolation.

Here's a couple of examples where using double quotes makes perfectly sense:

```
$ echo "We're good!" | sed "s/'re/ are/"
We are good!

$ name="John"; echo "Hello, I'm <name>." | sed "s/<name>/$name/"
Hello, I'm John.
```

It seems that double quotes enable some nice functionality, so why not always use them? The main reason for me is not always seeing what command is actually being executed by `sed`. It's very simple when the command is enclosed in single quotes: what you see is exactly what `sed` sees. When using double quotes, however, your string is going to be interpreted by the shell before being passed on to `sed`, and you must take into account any modifications, some of which might not be what you want. Here's a good example:

```
$ echo 'SELECT `date` FROM `services`' | sed 's/`date`/`uptime`/'
SELECT `uptime` FROM `services`
```

If you had used double quotes, here's what your actual `sed` command would have been like:

```
$ sed "s/`date`/`uptime`/"
$ sed 's/Wed May 29 08:28:20 UTC 2019/ 08:28:20 up 13 days,  1:29,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.02, 0.00/'
```

---

You can often get away with double quotes in connection to `sed`, because use of the `$` sign tends to be unambiguous:

```
$ line="back"; echo "front" | sed "s/front$/$line/"
back
$ line="back"; echo "frontline" | sed "s/front$/$line/"
frontline
$ line="-line"; echo "front-line" | sed "s/front$line/back$line/"
back-line
```

Things become more complicated if you're writing `awk` or `perl`, where `$` has more uses:

```
$ echo "col1 col2 col3" | awk '{print $1}'
col1
$ echo "col1 col2 col3" | awk "{print $1}"
col1 col2 col3

$ echo "col1 col2 col3" | perl -lane 'print $F[0]'
col1
$ echo "col1 col2 col3" | perl -lane "print $F[0]"
ARRAY(0x564346f18db0)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is actually related to bash, rather than just the `sed` command.

You can understand it better by looking at this example:

```
~ $ front="front"
~ $ echo "front" | sed "s/$front/back/"
back
~ $ echo "front" | sed 's/$front/back/'
front
```

Double quotes evaluate the expression inside, whereas single quotes preserve the literal value of each character. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

Just share one more example to illustrate the different results caused by single and double quotes.

When there is a backslash, single `\` is not enough, and another one `\` is needed to escape `\`, that is

```bsh
$ echo "\alpha" | sed 's/\\alpha/\\beta/'
\beta
```

but for double quotes, we need three quotes,

```bsh
$ echo "\alpha" | sed "s/\\alpha/\\beta/"
\alpha
$ echo "\alpha" | sed "s/\\\alpha/\\\beta/"
\beta
```

since one `\` has been used up when interpreting in the shell.

Moreover, if we want to insert before the given string, one more `\` is necessary,

```bsh
$ echo "\alpha" | sed '/alpha/i \\\beta'
\beta
\alpha
```

The reason I am not sure, but according to the manual, there is indeed a `\` after the command `i`,

```bsh
       i \

       text   Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.
```

While for double quotes, two more backslashes are needed,

```bsh
$ echo "\alpha" | sed "/alpha/i \\\\\beta"
\beta
\alpha
```