# How to send JSON as variable with bash curl?

Tags: bash, curl, json

I'm trying to send a POST request with curl, but I'd like to store the json data in a variable in order to resend it if an error occur.
I used this code:

```
jsonvariable="{"ora" : "value1", "temp" : "value2", "rh" : "value3", "lat" : "value4", "longi" : "value5"}"


curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '$jsonvariable' http://localhost:8080/updates
```

but the format after the `-d` option is not correct. Can you help me?

this code:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"ora" : "value1", "id" : "value2", "temp" : "value3","rh" : "value4", "lat" : "value5", "longi" : "value6"}' http://localhost:8080/updates
```

gives no errors instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used single quotes which prevent the variable from being expanded. Use double quotes instead:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$jsonvariable" http://localhost:8080/updates
```

If your variable content contains double quotes you can quote them with e.g. backslashes.

You can omit `-X POST` here because POST is the default method if you specify data to send with `-d`.

Further reading on quoting in `bash`: [How do I enter a file or directory with special characters in its name?](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051)

Comment: That's reducing the problem to a more difficult one. How do I properly escape `$jsonvariable` then?

Comment: @DirkGroeneveld How is proper quotation a more difficult problem? It seems like you have a new question, if so please ask it: [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: That's not fair @dessert, that's a *part* of this question, at least it *should* be part of your answer otherwise your answer is incomplete. If every SO answer was like this there'd be 10 times as many questions asked and everyone would get frustrated. It's nice of you to try to provide an answer, but your attempt is very short and clearly incomplete.