# Using "" in shellscript

Tags: command-line, scripts, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

i need to use a ffmpeg command in a shellscript

The command is the next one

```
(ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -f hls -i $(youtube-dl -f 95 -g $ylink) -c:v h264_nvenc -r 50 -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 /home/build/MSS-ONE/temp/cache/project-$intnumber/$project.m3u8 2>/home/build/MSS-ONE/temp/logs/$project-$intnumber/$project-$intnumber-cache.log) &
```

I need to get the result of the embeded command `$(youtube-dl -f 95 -g $ylink)` with quotes so the result in shellscript must be something like this

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -f hls -i "https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_playlist/expire/1566607293/ei/XTNgXdq4B8O-gwP_7Kn4CA/ip/158.50.77.241/id/-1xif50QMr4.365/itag/95/source/yt_live_broadcast/requiressl/yes/ratebypass/yes/live/1/goi/160/sgoap/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D140/sgovp/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D136/hls_chunk_host/r2---sn-p5qs7nek.googlevideo.com/playlist_type/DVR/initcwndbps/6590/mm/44/mn/sn-p5qs7nek/ms/lva/mv/m/mvi/1/pl/20/dover/11/keepalive/yes/beids/9466588/mt/1566585624/disable_polymer/true/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,ratebypass,live,goi,sgoap,sgovp,playlist_type/sig/ALgxI2wwRQIhANz10pUs-d4j0UXRSjzBYPXfyX4ud8mJMMbr9atpDZK_AiBzHkWNXpg2ALK0mnAZPiF_c_U6wQ6Kl5sIUwPlFoNm1A%3D%3D/lsparams/hls_chunk_host,initcwndbps,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl/lsig/AHylml4wRAIgddN210SkarxEUx0auCxF6miMbA4XLtVo9-G89HDI8bYCIGraEMZ7VL9cvMLlVKifc5pVB6EbAOq8-PqmMES4dpWG/playlist/index.m3u8" -c:v h264_nvenc -r 50 -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 /home/build/MSS-ONE/temp/cache/TN-4474fe64/TN.m3u8
```

I dont know how to do it.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

---

Nope, is not working, putting double quotes send this to the console

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -f hls -i https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_playlist/expire/1566609044/ei/NDpgXer1Htnlhwa4vp-oDg/ip/158.50.77.241/id/-1xif50QMr4.365/itag/95/source/yt_live_broadcast/requiressl/yes/ratebypass/yes/live/1/goi/160/sgoap/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D140/sgovp/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D136/hls_chunk_host/r2---sn-p5qlsndz.googlevideo.com/playlist_type/DVR/initcwndbps/4760/mm/44/mn/sn-p5qlsndz/ms/lva/mv/m/mvi/1/pl/20/dover/11/keepalive/yes/beids/23806817/mt/1566587361/disable_polymer/true/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,ratebypass,live,goi,sgoap,sgovp,playlist_type/sig/ALgxI2wwRQIhANzUWftly6fgAs-gftCO1M43sYH0onbO_bUDKNzspTkgAiB6V595Uxr0lfPVvyziI-goB5l547cW9JVqQ39qtOLjJw%3D%3D/lsparams/hls_chunk_host,initcwndbps,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl/lsig/AHylml4wRQIgaTR8rH6lv5snP84oaRxyDHbN2CYKc-A03aQSGHpZRs4CIQDzZdGeSXbcdm9OGethv32zwX4rvzHB7saxdrAiIXNWng%3D%3D/playlist/index.m3u8 -c:v h264_nvenc -r 50 -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 /home/build/MSS-ONE/temp/cache/TN-c21df74c/TN.m3u8
```

You can see the quotes are not in the command.

Edit:

i tested with chamorros suggestion and get some news, it works in the console, but not in the shellscript (i don know why).

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Project Name: " project
read -p "Enter Youtube Link Name: "  ylink
intnumber=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 8)
hlslink=$(echo \"$(youtube-dl -f 95 -g $ylink)\")
ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -f hls -i $hlslink -c:v h264_nvenc -r 50 -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 /home/build/MSS-ONE/temp/cache/$project-$intnumber/$project.m3u8
```

This gives me an error saying **"No such file or directory"**.

I think the problem is from ffmpeg and variables.

Thanks for trying.

Comment: Please show the command in the context of your whole script.

Comment: That depends entirely on the command’s context, please [edit] and provide your script.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but would this work `$(echo \"$(youtube-dl -f 95 -g $ylink)\")`

Answer (score 3):

You just put the double quotes around the command substitution:

```
… -i "$(youtube-dl -f 95 -g $ylink)" -c:v …
```

As I explain in detail in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051), double quotes *don’t* preserve the literal value of `$`, so the command substitution is evaluated although it’s quoted. That’s not the case for single quotes – let’s look at a simple example:

```
$ echo "$(whoami)"
dessert
$ echo '$(whoami)'
$(whoami)
```

In the first case with double quotes the command substitution is evaluated and `echo` prints my username `dessert`, in the second with single quotes the command substitution is not evaluated and the string is printed as-is.

---

When I run `youtube-dl -f 95 -g` followed by a youtube video link, for some I get:

```
ERROR: requested format not available
```

You could add a test for that, e.g.:

```
if ! hlslink=$(youtube-dl -gf22 "$file"); then
  exit
fi
ffmpeg … -i "$hlslink" …
```

This sets the `hlslink` variable and if that’s unsuccessful exits the script. I didn’t add an error message because the one `youtube-dl` prints is quite good.

Comment: Yes but i want dessert with double quotes, like "dessert"

Comment: @Pablo then try \"$(whoami)\".