# How to access directory with non-ascii, \n character in dir name

Tags: bash, directory, cd, special-characters, ascii

I have some data saved in a directory which has a non-ascii character in the name, how can I access the data within?

The directory appears as:

```
w0p6_t[[0.53.5]?[1.71.2]]
```

But escaping the special characters using `\` before them does not work, nor does surrounding the directory name with quotes as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/101592/905346).

I believe this "?" is a new line character (ascii `\012`) as `ls -lb` returns:

```
w0p7_t[[0.53.5]\n[1.71.2]]
```

I can see the contents of the directory using the `tree`
command, which shows the directory as:

```
w0p6_t[[0.53.5]\012[1.71.2]]
```

along with all of its content.

I have also tried:

```
cd "w0p7_t[[0.53.5]\n[1.71.2]]"
cd "w0p7_t[[0.53.5]\012[1.71.2]]"
```

and

```
cd w1p0_t\[\[0.53.5]\\012\[1.71.2\]\]
cd w1p0_t\[\[0.53.5]\\n\[1.71.2\]\]
```

with no success.

Also, attempting to auto-complete the command using <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not prompt suggestions for this directory.

Comment: you can type the first half `cd 'w0p7_t[[0.53.5]` <enter> and you will get a new line starting with `>` there you type the rest `[1.71.2]]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways (there are likely more)

1. an *un*quoted `?` will match any single character - including the newline character. So for example

   ```
   cd w0p6_t\[\[0.53.5\]?\[1.71.2\]\]
   ```

   or

   ```
   cd 'w0p6_t[[0.53.5]'?'[1.71.2]]'
   ```
2. you could use bash `$'string'` ANSI escaping to expand a `\n` sequence

   ```
   cd $'w0p6_t[[0.53.5]\n[1.71.2]]'
   ```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer.