# Permissions - How do I delete files from an external drive that requires root permissions?

Tags: command-line, usb, permissions

Okay, I'm at a loss as to what to do. I was trying to set up a bootable USB using "UNetBootin" and I didn't properly check where my stuff was actually installing to, so instead of installing to the external drive I was planning to use everything started to install to my 4 TB eHDD. Thankfully, nothing was lost... however, every single file that was added I am unable to delete through normal means. I keep getting an error every time I try to delete one of these folders that says "Error removing file /media/(myname)/My Passport/boot/en-us: Permission denied". Checking properties, I found that these files belonged to "root" and that I can't do anything because I'm not the owner.

I've tried opening a terminal so I could rm -rf these stubborn files, but I can't even access my eHDD with it. Typing that directory into the terminal gives me the error "bash: cd: too many arguments". Same thing happens when dragging the folder into the Terminal.

(If it's worth anything, I was trying to set up a Windows 10 bootable USB in case I ever wanted/needed to switch back.)

Comment: Too many arguments? Did you quote the path? https://askubuntu.com/q/101587/158442

Comment: No, I didn't. Didn't even know that you could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type "sudo " in front of your command and enclose the path and filename in quotes.  The quotes are needed because of the space character in your path.

So your command would look more like this:
`sudo rm -rf "/media/(myname)/My Passport/boot/en-us/filename"`

You will have to enter your password for the sudo command to work.