# I'm trying to set wallpaper from terminal in ubuntu and it's not working

Tags: gnome, python

I'm trying to set wallpaper from terminal in ubuntu and it's not working, i'm using this command:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://path_to_file"`

Command to get the image is working properly:
`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri`

This is my project on github - https://github.com/Vitalya-code/Wallpaper

Also i am ukrainian and i can write with errors

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem with the way you're running `gsettings` from Python? Have you tried running the actual command in CLI?

Comment: Perhaps you got the pathname of your file wrong. We cannot tell because you do not tell.

Comment: Thanks you for help, there is full command - 

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "/home/vitalya/archive/Python/Wallpaper/imgs/General 1920x1200 nature landscape river Jasper National Park mountains Canada.jpg"

Comment: @muru I'm trying to do this from the terminal for the first

Comment: Linux paths can't have spaces in them. Remove the spaces from the file name, or use quotations around the file name, or "escape" the spaces.

Comment: @Nmath Can you show me an example? This is full command: 

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "/home/vitalya/archive/Python/Wallpaper/imgs/General 1920x1200 nature landscape river Jasper National Park mountains Canada.jpg"

Comment: @Nmath also i have tried this:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "/home/vitalya/archive/Python/Wallpaper/imgs/random.jpg"

Comment: See: [How do I enter a file or directory with special characters in its name?](https://askubuntu.com/q/101587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file://path_to_file"
```

Instead of this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://path_to_file"
```